# Why my split conditional component not work in ssis?

Tags: ssis

I'm beginner in ssis,create this simple plan:
[image]

in the conditional split write this condition:

```
SUBSTRING( [Column1] ,12, 1 )=="1"
```

but i get this error on the conditional split component:
[image]

How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: The error message literally tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the Column1 is type DT_TEXT which is not accepted for the SUBSTRING function in SSIS expression builder.

You can change the type in the Flat File Connection Manager Editor in the Advanced tab at the Column1 DataType. SUBSTRING (SSIS Expression) works only with the DT_WSTR.

I hope this help.